# Homeomorphism between $R^1 \times S^1 $ & $ R^2 -(0,0)$

Tags: general-topology

My question is in the context of topological spaces. I can show that if $X_1$ & $X_2$ are homeomorphism and $Y_1$ & $Y_2$ are homeomorphism, then $X_1 \times Y_1$ & $X_2 \times Y_2$ are homeomorphism too.
Can I use this property to show homeomorphism between
$R^1 \times S^1 $ & $ R^2 -(0,0)$ ?

If not, can we do this using only a function like $f(x,t)=x^t$?

Comment: a space can not be a homeomorphism, what you probably mean is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are homeomorphic, i.e. there is a homeomorphism $X_1\to X_2$ between them.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go from the punctured plane to the cylinder. We know that the positive reals $(0,\infty)$ are homeomorphic to the real line $\mathbb R$. Let $g$ be a homeomorphim from the positive reals to the reals.

We use polar coordinates in the punctured plane and define $f$ by $$f(r,\theta)=(1, \theta, g(r))$$

Notice the $1$ in the codomain. Technically speaking, we can remove the $1$ and give a two dimensional parameterization of the cylinder which is expected if it is homeomorphic to a subset of the plane.

I leave it to you to prove that this is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Intuitively, what does that 1 mean? (I'm trying to picture it visually).

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates we have $(r,\theta, z)$. Since the cylinder has radius $1$ or some constant in the general case, the $1$ is $r$.

Comment: Your answer was super helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Generous hint; not a complete solution**

You can't apply that theorem here, no, because the right-hand side is not a product in any obvious way.

I suggest you look at
$$
f(s, \theta) = (s \cos \theta, s \sin \theta).
$$

That would be a perfect solution if the left hand side were $\Bbb R^{+} \times S^1$. You should work through that carefully to see why.

And then you should modify it to work for all of $\Bbb R$ instead of just the positive part of the real line.